# Enable button when the sum of inputs is an especific number with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Please, i need help with this code. i need to enable the submit when the sum of all the other `inputs == 10` in this case. please!!!

```
<form>
  <p>
    if the sum is
    <input name="total" type="text" value="10" readonly="readonly">
    must be enable the button,otherwise it kept disabled
  </p>
  <input name="sum1" type="number"></br>
  <input name="sum2" type="number"></br>
  <input name="sum3" type="number"></br>
  <input name="go" value="calculate" type="button" disabled="disabled"></br>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried anything from your side?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[name="sum1"],input[name="sum2"],input[name="sum3"]').on('change keyup paste', function(){
       var sum = +$('input[name="sum1"]').val() + +$('input[name="sum2"]').val() + +$('input[name="sum3"]').val();
       console.log(sum);
       if(sum == 10) {
         $('input[name="go"]').prop('disabled', false);
       } else {
         $('input[name="go"]').prop('disabled', true);
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    if the sum is
    <input name="total" type="text" value="10" readonly="readonly">
    must be enable the button,otherwise it kept disabled
  </p>
  <input name="sum1" type="number"></br>
  <input name="sum2" type="number"></br>
  <input name="sum3" type="number"></br>
  <input name="go" value="calculate" type="button" disabled="disabled"></br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to get each value with `input[name=input_name]` then use the unary plus operator to convert them to numbers

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
  var nbr1=$('input[name=sum1]').val();
  var nbr2=$('input[name=sum2]').val();
  var nbr3=$('input[name=sum3]').val();
  var sum=0;
  sum= +nbr1+ +nbr2+ +nbr3;
  console.log(sum)
  if(sum==10){
    $('input[name=go]').attr('disabled', false)
  }
  else{
    $('input[name=go]').attr('disabled', true)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<p>
if the sum is
<input name="total" type="text" value="10" readonly="readonly">
must be enable the button,otherwise it kept disabled
</p>
<input name="sum1" type="number"><br>
<input name="sum2" type="number"><br>
<input name="sum3" type="number"><br>
<input name="go" value="calculate" type="button" disabled="disabled"><br>
</form>
```